# Does having a significant result from chi-squared test for independence also means that the odds ratio is significantly different from 1?

Tags: chi-squared-test, independence, odds-ratio, odds

Suppose I have 2 by 2 contingency table. I performed Pearson's chi-squared test for independence and the results are significant. Does that mean the odds ratio that I calculated based on the 2 by 2 table is also significantly different from 1? I would say not necessarily since they are based on different kind of statistical test even though there is overlap in hypothesis. Please advise.

Comment: Which test are you using to get a p-value for the odds ratio?

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, thanks for the comment. I am using Wald test based on Maximum likelihood estimate of ln(odds ratio).